# Is there a field like unread by owner on Case?

Tags: apex, case, case-auto-response

I want to measure the first response time or first view time on a case. Is there something similar to unread by owner on Case? Do I need to create custom fields for this?

Answer (score 2):

to get last view date you can use `LastViewedDate` field on `Case`

> The timestamp for when the current user last viewed this record. If
>   this value is null, this record might only have been referenced
>   (LastReferencedDate) and not viewed.

`[select id, LastViewedDate from Case]`